# php mail() isn't working

Tags: php, sendmail, email

i just figured out that the `mail()` function isn't working

i'm under Debian, i installed postfix because a friend told me to (although i didn't configure it).

When i do a phpinfo() i've got :

```
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

but in this directories i don't have anything  like `sendmail`

Do you have an idea, on what i should do to get mail() working ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unix, most programs rely on a MTA (message transfer agent) to do mail transmission. When a program wants to send a message, it executes `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and gives it the entire message in stdin.

The Sendmail MTA was the first one to work this way (and still does), and other MTAs follow the same convention of providing a `/usr/sbin/sendmail` program.

*[In this answer, Sendmail is the original MTA, and `sendmail` (lowercase) is `/usr/sbin/sendmail` (which comes with all MTAs currently used).]*

PHP's `mail()` follows the Unix tradition and just passes the message to the `sendmail` executable. Which means you need a MTA. You already installed Postfix, which is good. However, it *does* have a `sendmail` binary, so if you don't have it in `/usr/sbin/`, then you must have installed it elsewhere -- perhaps `/usr/local/sbin/` if compiled from source?

Reinstalling Postfix may fix the problem. If it doesn't, please update your question with details such as how did you install Postfix in the first place.

If your `sendmail` is somewhere else than `/usr/sbin/`, then you will have to edit PHP's configuration -- `php.ini`. It's usually in `/etc/php5/`, and Debian has *three* of those. (`cgi/` is for generic CGI/FCGI, `apache2/` is for the Apache PHP module, `cli/` is for when PHP is used from command line.)